# An integral of a rational function of logarithm and nonlinear arguments

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This problem was posted in I&S

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{\log x \log (1+x) \log (1+x+x^{2})}{(1-x)(1+x^{2})}\,\mathrm{d}x \approx -0.223434.$$

I am not sure if there exists a closed form but it seems worth trying. I am completely clueless on how to start with this beast. It is worth saying that$$1-x^3= (1-x)(1+x+x^2).$$ That seems to go no where. I think the integral can be represented as the derivative of the integral representation of the Hypergeometric function but I am not comfortable with that. Any ideas ?

Comment: That should depend on third derivatives of beta functions, by writing $(1+x)$ as $\frac{1-x^2}{1-x}$ and $1+x+x^2$ as $\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}$.

Comment: this is really a monster ...omg

Comment: @tired The user who posted is called Laplace'sDemon, so yeah.

Comment: Maybe the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$ is helping to compute this monster

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, your comment gives the impression that the question is solved but it isn't clear if that will result to the derivative of the beta function. At least I can't see it that straight forward.

Comment: @FDP, I doubt this will help because of the terms $1+x^2,1-x^3$.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: this is very far from being settled, I just said *should*, but I am actually too lazy to check if my first impression was correct.

Comment: We need @Cleo to provide a closed form :( .

Comment: yeah that Demon would be me @ZaidAlyafeai , posted this on I&S, was unsolved there now unsolved here too :)

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light, what is the source of this integral ?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, bet you can.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I certainly don't want to discourage you from solving this problem if you actually can, but you should be warned. Many integrals like these with three or more logarithmic factors in the numerator often seem incredibly scary at first, only then after hours/months of hard work revealed to be *even* scarier than you ever could have imagined.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, hope you can write a partial answer before the Bounty ends.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai unlikely. I'm in the middle of moving right now, and even though I'm mostly done with the first of the integrals I have to come up with some bright idea for canceling out poles using Principle Value. I think I know a route that will work, but it's tedious and I want to pursue a cleaner solution. Once I feel like I've accomplished some good work toward a closed form I'll post it.

Comment: Link to I&S thread: http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic814.html

Comment: the interpreted requirement that answer should be in closed form would be more palatable if the answer in the OP question had not been stated as a numerical approximation

Comment: This ISC has no answer for -0.2234343508699  http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

Comment: @phdmba7of12 I think if the OP provides a numerical approximation *and* explicitly asks for a closed form, then the goal of the question should be fairly clear.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes to be honest.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai Eh, its 2 downvotes out of 12. I'll call them outliers, just ignore them.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, I rarely do get downvotes on my questions and that quickly, hence my concern.

Comment: Products of $\ln(x-z_i)$ really chaotic with 3 or more of them, look at this simpler integral for example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln(x%2Bz_1)ln(x%2Bz_2)%2F(x-z_3).
It consists of the polylogarithm function and is fairly complicated and not fun to work with. And this is a product of 2 logarithms, not even 3 as you are asking (Wolfram can't do more than 2). As a result, unless you consider polylogarithms to be a closed form, in which case you should probably accept user90369's note, I don't think this will evaluate to anything nice.

Comment: @IsaacBrowneIs you are considering indefinite integral in the link. Definite integrals usually have much nicer closed form not necessarily involving polylogs.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai I seemingly made a small amount of progress on this problem a while back, but school interrupted me. I would have to look at my notes to get the details, but it would seem that one of the constituent integrals found by breaking this one up can be expressed more simply in terms of generalized harmonic numbers along with elementary functions.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, oh okay. Good to hear that.

Comment: Let $$I_{ab}~=~\displaystyle\int_0^1\ln\Big(1-x^a\Big)\ln\Big(1-x^b\Big)~\ln(x)~\frac1{1-x}~dx,$$ and $$J_{ab}~=~\displaystyle\int_0^1\ln\Big(1-x^a\Big)\ln\Big(1-x^b\Big)~\ln(x)~\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}~dx.$$ Then $$\int_0^1\cdots~dx~=~\dfrac{(I_{11}+J_{11})-(I_{12}+J_{12})-(I_{13}+J_{13})+(I_{23}+J_{23})}2,$$ and $$I_1~=~-\dfrac{\pi^4}{45}.$$

Answer (score 6):

I couldn’t find a closed form with traditional functions and constants. Therefore, as a *note* :

Be $\,m\in\mathbb{N}\,$, $\,a\in\mathbb{R}\,$ with $\,a>-3$ . $\mod{}$ means "Modulo" (see: division with rest).

And be $\,\delta_{i,j}\,$ the *Kronecker delta* which means: $\,\delta_{i,j}=1\,$ for $\,i=j\,$ and $\,\delta_{i,j}=0\,$ otherwise.

Using the Taylor series for $\,\ln(1+x) \,$, $\,\ln(1-x^m)\,$, $\,\displaystyle\frac {1}{1-x}\,$, $\,\displaystyle \frac {1}{1+x^2}$ we get:

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x) \ln(1-x^m)}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}x^a dx  =$

$\displaystyle =\frac{m}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+3+a}  \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (1+\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}(2n-2k+1)))\sum\limits_{v=0}^k \frac{(-1)^{k-v+1}\delta_{0,(\text{$v+1$ mod $m$)}}}{(k-v+1)(v+1)}$

With the derivation with respect to $\,a\,$ and then $\,a:=0\,$ follows:

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^1 \frac{\ln(x) \ln(1+x) \ln(1+x+x^2)}{(1-x)(1+x^2)} dx = $

$\displaystyle =\int\limits_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x) \ln(1-x^3)}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}\ln(x) dx - \int\limits_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x) \ln(1-x)}{(1-x)(1+x^2)}\ln(x) dx $

$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+3)^2}  \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (1+\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}(2n-2k+1)))\sum\limits_{v=0}^k \frac{(-1)^{k-v+1}(1-3\cdot\delta_{0,(\text{$v+1$ mod $3$) }})}{(k-v+1)(v+1)}$