# How to evaluate this logarithmic integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\ln(x)\ln(1+x)\ln(1+x+x^{2})}{(1-x)(1+x^{2})}\,dx$$
I posted this on I&S but there was no response , so posting it here.
Wolfram gave $-0.223434$, can it be evaluated in terms of special functions functions?

Comment: Why does this look like it can to you? It's not hard to write down an integral that can't be more simply represented

Comment: Given that we are on $(0,1)$ where the natural logarithm has a simple, convergent Taylor Series we might be able to do this with a careful interchange of multi-summation and integration... Not sure what the best way to set this up would be though

Comment: Question already asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242141/an-integral-of-a-rational-function-of-logarithm-and-nonlinear-arguments but not already solved

Comment: Note that there is now a bounty on that question @FDP hopefully someone can answer it.